# display a meta item with every product where multiple products are shown on one page ( i.e. not just the single product pages )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when i show a few products on a wordpress page from a woocommerce product table i would like to show the short description + a link to an associated pdf ( ideally using a pdf icon as the link )

i have managed to get the short description to show by using the following code - but how do i add something in the meta data that's been added to the product as ( Meta: pdf_link ) - it's a url to a .pdf file

> add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woo_show_excerpt_shop_page', 5 );
>
> function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page() {
>     global $product;
>
> echo $product->post->post_excerpt;
>
> .
>   }

i'm assuming i can just add another line like:

echo $product->post->pdf_link;

???

but i cant work it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
$pdf_link = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'pdf_link', true );

echo $pdf_link;
```

Comment: thanks will get a chance tonight and get back to you :-)